# Display value as my need if condition exists in jsf

Tags: jsf

I have following

```
<h:outputText value="#{verifyTxnList.resolved}"/>
```

and there will be display record either `Y` or `N`.
But what I actually want is:

if value is `Y` then display `Yes` else if `N` then `No`.

Is there any idea to add logic on view part only  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a conditional operator in EL within the `value` attribute:

```
<h:outputText value="#{verifyTxnList.resolved == 'Y' ? 'Yes' : 'No'}"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use of conditional operator is one choice, especially if it will be used on single place in application.
If you are looking for cleaner solution which will be used on many places in your application, `Converter` seems as better solution to me:

```
@FacesConverter("myYesNoConverter")
public class YesNoConverter implements Converter {

   public static final String YES = "Yes", NO = "No";
   public static final String Y = "Y", N = "N";

   @Override
   public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, 
                             String value) {
      if(YES.equals(value)) {
         return Y;
      }
      return N;
   }

   @Override
   public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, 
                             Object value) {
      if(Y.equals(value)) {
         return YES;
      }
      return NO;
   }    
}
```

On places where you want to convert your output, just refer to `myYesNoConverter` like this.

```
<h:outputText value="#{verifyTxnList.resolved}" converter="myYesNoConverter"/>
```

This way your conversion logic isn't repeated many times across your application and can be easily modified.

**UPDATE**

If you have JSF 1.2 you have to register your converter in `faces-config.xml`.

```
<converter>
    <description>My implementation of Yes No converter</description>
    <converter-id>myYesNoConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>
        org.example.YesNoConverter
    </converter-class>
</converter>
```

and remove `@FacesConverter("myYesNoConverter")` annotation

Comment: It did not work to me. Got `myYesNoConverter` exception on runtime.

Comment: What version of JSF do you have? What kind of exception?

Comment: Previous comment was unclear so sorry for that. I have jsf version `1.2` and I added above code inside `YesNoConverter .java` class. When I run application and went to that page where I am implementing this logic, this page is not displayed. It throws `myYesNoConverter ` not found exception.

Comment: One more doubt. May I use this code in simple java class or I have to use inside `ManagedBean`. When I tried first I used this in simple java class but did not work and I used making `ManagedBean`.

Comment: If you register it in `web.xml` the it is just simple java class. You reference it using converter-id

Comment: This is not accepting on my `web.xml`. Is there any parent tag for `<converter>...</converter>`

Comment: Sorry it should be `faces-config.xml` :) I have updated my answer

Comment: I had already solved My problem using `kocko's` logic. But I am trying your logic. It is displaying only `No`. I will try myself by using your logic. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If all you can get is `Y` or `N`

Then:

```
 <h:outputText value="#{verifyTxnList.resolved eq 'Y'?'Yes':'No'}"/>
```